# GET Request every interval time, with errors handling

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

I think the question is simple, but I can't repair this code by self.

I have one service doing some GET request. The GET usually returns 200, but some times it's returning 410.

I want to make requests every some interval, for example every second.
The problem is when I am using an observable mechanism for this, it fails at first "410", then it returning 410 on console in infinity.

My service code:

```
getStatistic(){
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/resource',options)
  .retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(5000))
  .map(
  (response:Response) => {
    return response.json();
  }
)
  }



 handleError(error:any){
    if(error.status === 404){
      return Observable.of(false)
    }else if(error.status===410){
      return Observable.throw({code:error.status, msg:error._body})
    }else{
      return Observable.of(false)
    }
  }
```

And the Observable:

```
var observable =  TimerObservable.create(5000, 1000)
  .takeWhile(() => true)
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.statisticService.getStatistic()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log("data",data)
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("err",err)
        }
      );
  },error2 => console.log("error"));
```

The responses are going like this:
200
200
200
200
410 <- for this moment all responses aren't from requests to server, only cached
410
410
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because

> A 410 response is cacheable by default.

Client caches that response and doesn't even try to call the server anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to change the way you think of the of the problem and start to think more functionally and reactively. 
This is easier said than done but with practice this would become a second nature and might make a lot of your code much easier to comprehend about.

Let us tackle each of the problems one by one.

1. Reduce the number of newly formed data structures like arrays and objects. Instead pipe outputs of one function as an input to another function.
2. Currently you are subscribing to an observable per api call. To chain all api calls and call them in parallel, we could use "forkJoin". Note that there a lot of operators like "forkJoin" and it is strenuous to know all of them. I needed to google "rxjs observables parallel" to know that "forkJoin" is the one we need.
3. If we need to convert the data structure that arrives from the observable to another data structure, we would need to use the "map" operator
4. If we need to data that arrives from the observable to fulfill a certain predicate, we would need to use the "filter" operator
5. If we need to get the response from one an observable before calling another observable, we would use the operator "flatMap"
6. You could always console.log inside any operator to know what data is arriving
   Ex: `forkJoin(...obsSources).map(x=> {
        console.log(x)
    })`
7. If you are stuck and could not find an operator that solves your problem, you could subscribe to the observable and call other functions from with the subscribe function that gets its arguments from what the subscribe function emits (instead of creating a new array or object)
   Ex: `forkJoin(...obsSources).subcribe(x=> {
        func1(x)
    })`

I solved the problem without testing the code so probably it won't be working for your special case but I wanted to share how things actually work with rxjs observables.

```
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin";
const obsSources = distinctDataAssIDs
                  .map(dataASSID=>this.api.getDataAssociationByID(dataASSID))
forkJoin(...obsSources)
.map(arrResults => arrResults.map(arrResult=> 
arrResult.body.entities.DATAASSOCIATIONS[0]))
.filter(dataAss => dataAss.DATAOBJECTS !== undefined)
.map(dataAss =>  Array.from(new Set(dataAss.DATAOBJECTS)))
.flatMap(secondMethodResult => this.service.thirdMethod(secondMethodResult))
```